# grep command that matches lines with letters in alphabetical order

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I need help figuring out a regular expression with grep that will search a file and display lines that put [a-z] in alphabetical order in each 'set' separately (it will become clear with the examples)

Valid matches examples:

```
a96d7e75-4432-41de-835c-625a636c1914 prefranks
b028224d-314b-4b03-a873-1436838f9233 escape
```

Invalid matches examples:

```
c69f34e8-905e-4ce8-7893-a3e271d6f48c reconvince
e9db0700-f72b-4bea-ae37-e18ec6ca80d3 lumberjacks
```

I used:

```
egrep '^([^a-f-]*a?[^a-f-]*b?[^a-f-]*c?[^a-f-]*d?[^a-f-]*e?[^a-f-]*f?-){4}[^a-f-]*a?[^a-f-]*b?[^a-f-]*c?[^a-f-]*d?[^a-f-]*e?[^a-f-]*f?[0-9]* ' text.txt
```

it didn't give any invalid matches but it left out valid examples like the following and I can't figure out why:

```
6cd11113-bcf3-4f73-85f5-145b49225244 neoconservative
96239f18-5c62-495a-b1f8-50759443b885 fellest
51771125-b4d8-4cf8-a3d9-67117263f708 macular
a266f798-d772-47f0-9bdf-451939c2007e buntings
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland My apologies for the long question, I thought my command would only need a couple changes but meters in regex is not what I expected. It's a small task that requested the answer to be short and to be done with simple grep commands.

Comment: `egrep` has been deprecated for almost 20 years in favor of `grep -E`.

Comment: I owe you an apology. I initially said a regular expression would have to be  extremely long and highly complex. In fact, the needed regular expression is quite manageable.

Comment: @EdMorton However, `tar` has also been deprecated in favor of `pax`, and you know how that went.

Comment: In the string `a96d7e75-4432-41de-835c-625a636c1914 prefranks`, which you call valid, you have a "d" after an "e", a "c" after an "e", an "e" after an "r", an "a" after an "r" and a "k" after an "n" :-)

Comment: @Dominique the question isn't clear but I THINK the OP wants the letters to be in order just inside each `-`-separated segment such as `a96d7e75`, not across the whole first field or whole line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `egrep` fails for substrings with digits after an `f`.
It will work, when you replace `f?*-){4}` with `f?[^a-f]*-){4}`, resulting in

```
egrep '^([^a-f-]*a?[^a-f-]*b?[^a-f-]*c?[^a-f-]*d?[^a-f-]*e?[^a-f-]*f?[^a-f]*-){4}[^a-f-]*a?[^a-f-]*b?[^a-f-]*c?[^a-f-]*d?[^a-f-]*e?[^a-f-]*f?[0-9]* ' text.txt
```

It will be just as hard to read, but shorter, when you use a variable

```
x='[^a-f-]'
egrep "^($x*a?$x*b?$x*c?$x*d?$x*e?$x*f?$x*-){4}$x*a?$x*b?$x*c?$x*d?$x*e?$x*f?[0-9]* " text.txt
```

You can make a small loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  charline="${line//[0-9]/}"
  if [[ "$charline" =~ ^(a?b?c?d?e?f?-){4}(a?b?c?d?e?f?)\ .* ]]; then
    echo "${line}"
  fi
done < text.txt
```

The last solution can be made smaller (and harder to read):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ "${line//[0-9]/}" =~ ^(a?b?c?d?e?f?-){4}(a?b?c?d?e?f?)\ .* ]] &&
    echo "${line}"
done < text.txt
```

EDIT: Above solution does not accept double letters in a token.
When you want to accept these, change the solution to

```
#/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ "${line//[0-9]/}" =~ ^(a*b*c*d*e*f*-){4}(a*b*c*d*e*f*)\ .* ]] &&
    echo "${line}"
done < text.txt
```

Edit 2:
When you want to accept double letters, and know that the input is always like the given examples (tokens only `[0-9a-f]`, `-` between tokens and a space after the last token), you can use

```
grep -E '^([a0-9]*[b0-9]*[c0-9]*[d0-9]*[e0-9]*[f0-9]*[- ]){5}' text.txt
```

Comment: This breaks if you have more than one of the same letter, such as `aa96d7e75-4432...`

Comment: @dawg  The description asks for an alphabetical order, but OP's code was with unique letters as well. OP asked why some lines did not show with his code, so I looked for improvements in his code. I added a solution that does support repeated letters.

Answer (score 4):

You seems to want to validate the first part of the data before the first space. Those strings consists of chars a-f 0-9 and a hyphen.

If you can make use of `grep -P` or for example on mac `ggrep -P` for a Perl-compatible regular expression, you can use a negative lookahead to make sure that in that first part there is no char in the range of `[a-e]` after matching an `f`,  not char in the range of `[a-d]` after matching an `e` etc..

```
^(?![a-f\d-]*(?:f\d*[a-e]|e\d*[a-d]|d\d*[abc]|c\d*[ab]|b\d*a))[a-f\d]+(?:-[a-f\d]+){4}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not

  - `[a-f\d-]*` Match optional chars a-f, a digit or `-`
  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

    - `f\d*[a-e]` Match an `f`, optional digits and then one char in the range `[a-e]`
    - `|` Or
    - `e\d*[a-d]` Match an `e`, optional digits and then one char in the range of `[a-d]`
    - `|` Or
    - `d\d*[abc]` Same for `d`
    - `|` Or
    - `c\d*[ab]` Same for `c`
    - `|` Or
    - `b\d*a` Same for `b`
  - `)` Close the group
- `)` Close the lookbeahead
- `[a-f\d]+` Match 1+ chars a-f or a digit
- `(?:-[a-f\d]+){4}`  Repeat 4 times matching `-` and 1+ chars a-f or a digit followed by a space

Example with `grep -P`

```
grep -P '^(?![a-f\d-]*(?:f\d*[a-e]|e\d*[a-d]|d\d*[abc]|c\d*[ab]|b\d*a))[a-f\d]+(?:-[a-f\d]+){4} ' text.txt
```

Output

```
a96d7e75-4432-41de-835c-625a636c1914 prefranks
b028224d-314b-4b03-a873-1436838f9233 escape
6cd11113-bcf3-4f73-85f5-145b49225244 neoconservative
96239f18-5c62-495a-b1f8-50759443b885 fellest
51771125-b4d8-4cf8-a3d9-67117263f708 macular
a266f798-d772-47f0-9bdf-451939c2007e buntings
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z2C8pn/1)

Comment: Eyes straining regex :-)

Comment: @anubhava There's no denying here :-) Luckily the OP was already a bit used to it.

Comment: In the last edit of my answer a added a simple grep without (negative) lookaheads.

Comment: @WalterA Yes, but that would also match `-----` or 5 spaces

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to have a simple solution for well-behaving input. Supporting `-----` is possible with `grep -E '^([a0-9]*[b0-9]*[c0-9]*[d0-9]*[e0-9]*[f0-9]*[- ]+){5}' text.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Tough with Grep...

But given:

```
$ cat file
a96d7e75-4432-41de-835c-625a636c1914 prefranks
b028224d-314b-4b03-a873-1436838f9233 escape
c69f34e8-905e-4ce8-7893-a3e271d6f48c reconvince
e9db0700-f72b-4bea-ae37-e18ec6ca80d3 lumberjacks
```

You can use a Ruby:

```
ruby -lane 'puts $_ if $F[0].split(/-/).
                        map{|a| a.scan(/[a-f]/)}.all?{|a| a==a.sort}' file
```

Prints:

```
a96d7e75-4432-41de-835c-625a636c1914 prefranks
b028224d-314b-4b03-a873-1436838f9233 escape
```

Alternatively, any awk:

```
awk '{
    num_fields=split($1,fi,"-")
    for(f=1; f<=num_fields; f++) {
        gsub(/[^a-f]/,"",fi[f])
        if (length(fi[f])>1) 
            for(i=2; i<=length(fi[f]); i++) 
                if (substr(fi[f],i-1,1)>substr(fi[f],i,1)) next
    }
} 1' file
# same output
```

Comment: One could alternatively remove digits from `"aa96d7e75-44d3a2"` to produce `s = "aade-da"` then compare `s` with `s.gsub(/[a-z]+/) { |s| s.each_char.sort.join } #=> 
"aade-ad"`. As `s` differs from the string with sorted parts there is no match for this string (line). I don't recall the problem you mentioned with your earlier comment. Where I here have `gsub` I inadvertently wrote `scan` in an earlier comment. Using `split` is probably better, however.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the OP needs a grep solution for some reason but others with a similar problem reading this question in future may not have that same restriction.

Keeping in mind [this saying](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
> regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

and using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    str = $1
    gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",str)
    numSegs = split(str,segs,"-")
    for ( segNr=1; segNr<=numSegs; segNr++ ) {
        seg = segs[segNr]
        numChars = length(seg)
        currChar = substr(seg,1,1)
        for ( charNr=2; charNr<=numChars; charNr++ ) {
            prevChar = currChar
            currChar = substr(seg,charNr,1)
            if ( currChar <= prevChar ) {
                next
            }
        }
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
a96d7e75-4432-41de-835c-625a636c1914 prefranks
b028224d-314b-4b03-a873-1436838f9233 escape
6cd11113-bcf3-4f73-85f5-145b49225244 neoconservative
96239f18-5c62-495a-b1f8-50759443b885 fellest
51771125-b4d8-4cf8-a3d9-67117263f708 macular
a266f798-d772-47f0-9bdf-451939c2007e buntings
```

Comment: `gsub(/[0-9-]+/,"",str)` should be `gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",str)`

Comment: @WalterA right, fixed now thanks. I had messed it up changing from `[^a-f-]`.

Comment: `if ( currChar <= prevChar )` is OK when you accept letters appearing twice (IMHO the right interpretation of the question), and can simple be changed into `if ( currChar < prevChar )` when you do want to accept double letters. This flexibilty illustrates the strength of `awk`. In my solution this small detail requires a complete different solution.